# Flutter - Custom staggered grid view

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, staggered-gridview

I am using `flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.4` to build a menu of 5 elements (tiles) that I want to display according to a specific layout, below you will find an image of the desired output and the output I am currently having,
this is my code so far:

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14),
    child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: gridItems.length,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2,
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
                child: gridItems[index]);
        },
        staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
            return StaggeredTile.fit(2);
        }),
),
```

The closest I got is with :

• `StaggeredTile.fit(2)`

and

• `StaggeredTile.count(2, 1)`

which they both gave the same results.

This is the image:
[image]

Comment: another solution is that you make a 2x2 grid then expand a row under the grid and place your 5th item there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not what exactly you're looking for but

`StaggeredTile.fit(index.isEven ? 2 : 1);`

will give you an even display of 5 tiles on two lines

Comment: I went with it for the time being until I find the layout I am looking for.